# How to test subscribe with karma in ng2

Tags: angular, karma-runner

From service I get some stream, so in my component I get this like:

```
this.service.getSome().subscribe(x => this.invokeHere(x));
```

In my spec file i had something like this

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(SomeComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;

    service = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(Service);
    spy = spyOn(service, 'getSome')
        .and.returnValue(Observable.of(serviceStub));

    fixture.detectChanges();
});
```

Comment: whats the problem you are facing can you please add that also with quiz ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
it('test observable', inject([MockBackend], (mockBackend: MockBackend) => {
    mockBackend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
      connection.mockError(new Error());
    });
    service.someRequest()
      .subscribe(() => { },(err) => {
        // your test
      });
  }));
```